# Vue / JavaScript validate data in loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this **data** property :

```
mappingData: {
    id_feed: "",    
    projectFieldOptions: [],
},
```

This `projectFieldOptions` is filled up using a http call:

```
http.get("xml-fields")
    .then((response) => {
        let _this = this;
        _this.xmlFields.push({
            value: "do_not_import",
            text: "Do Not Import",
            id: 0,
        });
        response.data.forEach(function (item) {
            _this.xmlFields.push({
                value: item.field_slug,
                text: item.field_title,
                id: item.id_xml_field,
            });
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

So, this `projectFieldOptions` now contain this. **Basically each object represent a each dropdown box**.

```
[ { "value": "title", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "short_message", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "url", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_id", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "aff_code", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_url", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "other_data", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "product_id", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "created_at", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "product_active", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "brand", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "old_price", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "subcategory", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "category", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "price", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "widget_name", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_name", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "image_urls", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "description", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null } ]
```

In above output you can see I have a **array of object** and each **object** has **text** property which value initially is **Do Not Import**. But from the dropdown If I choose other option then this **text** property value will be changed.

Now, I want to show a `alert('success')` **IF** at least one **text** property value is not **Do Not Import** or **do_not_import** otherwise `alert('false')`

I mean user must select at least one value from the dropdown that is other than **Do Not Import** or **do_not_import**.

**What I am trying :**

```
watch : {
    mappingData: {
        handler(newData, oldData) {
            for( let key in newData.projectFieldOptions ) {
                if( newData.projectFieldOptions[key].text == 'Do Not Import' ||  newData.projectFieldOptions[key].text == 'do_not_import' ) {
                    alert('error');
                } else {
                    alert('false');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but above code is only work for the last dropdown list only. I mean this last dropdown:

[image]

Overall, I need to check user must choose **at least** one value from the dropdowns.

Comment: You can check if any of them is wrong [thanks to `some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Not sure if this is a good idea to make this in a `watch` tho, because you'll need to [use `deep`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers) and that it's probably not relevant to check that every time, rather once after you have fetched your data already.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that will tell you if you have a least one element that is not to be imported.

```js
const atLeastOneNotToImport = x.some(el => el.text === 'Do Not Import' || el.text === 'do_not_import')
console.log(atLeastOneNotToImport) // true
```

This is on top of my comment: [Vue / JavaScript validate data in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73423557/vue-javascript-validate-data-in-loop#comment129671674_73423557)

Comment: Thanks and I have managed the issue using `filter` function.